# Angular Radio Buttons form with unknown number of elements

Tags: html, angular

I am new to Angular and I have an issue with the radio buttons.

I have an array of strings which I want to use to create a form with radio buttons. I do not know the length or the content of the array - the values are taken from an external service.

How can I do this using a form builder in my Angular Component and in html file? Can it be something like this?

**question-dto.ts**

```
export class QuestionDto {
  questionText: string;
  questionOptions: string[];
}
```

**quiz.component.ts**

```
question: QuestionDto = new QuestionDto();
questionOptionsForm: any;

constructor(private quizService: QuizService,
            private formBuilder: FormBuilder) { }
ngOnInit() {
  this.initForm();
}

initForm() {
  this.questionOptionsForm = this.formBuilder.group({
    //INIT RADIO BUTTONS HERE
  })
}
```

**quiz.component.html**

```
<div>
  <p>
    Answers
  </p>
  <form *ngIf="questionOptionsForm">
    <div *ngFor="let option of question.questionOptions">
      <label>
        <input type="radio" class="form-control">
          {{option}}
      </label>
    </div>
  </form>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should try FormArray https://alligator.io/angular/reactive-forms-formarray-dynamic-fields/

code would look like:

```
initForm() {
    this.questionOptionsForm = this.formBuilder.group({
        options: this.formBuilder.array([this.createOption()])
    });
}
createOption():FormGroup {
    return this.formBuilder.group({
        name: '',
        description: ''
    });
}
```